# In MS Access, why would a SQL string work as a Query but not as a RecordSource of a Report?

Tags: ms-access

My question: Why would a SQL string function properly as a query but not as the RecordSource of a report?

I apologize for the lengthy background, but I think the context in which this issue is arising is probably helpful. In Access 2019, I have a MainQuery that is based upon *multiple* other queries, some of which are parameter queries.  So, MainQuery itself does not contain any parameters as part of its definition, but because its "constituent queries" contain parameters for which the user is prompted, running MainQuery prompts the user for said parameter values. Note that I call them "constituent queries" because they are all standalone query objects in my database as opposed to true subqueries within MainQuery.

MainQuery is the RecordSource of MainReport. Of course, upon opening MainReport, the user is prompted for the parameters that allow MainQuery (i.e. all its constituent queries) to run. Naturally, the user must reopen or refresh MainReport and supply different parameter values each time to see a different set of data inside MainReport.

This arrangement has worked well for years and continues to work, but I recently decided I wanted to increase the functionality of the database by allowing the user to print out multiple MainReport reports (for different records) in rapid succession.

The strategy I used was to consolidate MainQuery and all of its constituent queries into one big, complex MasterQuery made up of legitimate subqueries defined inside of it. The parameters for which the user used to be prompted each time the MainQuery was run were replaced with a simple string place holder, and the entire body of the MasterQuery is saved in a SQL_Table so that my VBA code can access it.  Now, the user can select the records for which he or she wishes to print on a form designed for this purpose. Then, upon clicking a button, my VBA code gathers the user's choices, retrieves the template SQL string from the SQL_Table, and for each record that the user wants to print, replaces the string place holders in the SQL string (previously known as the parameters) and assigns the RecordSource of MainReport to that SQL string.

As I was working on this project for the last week or so, I was able to get this process to work very beautifully and successfully.  But, as I continued developing it, I ended up making several additions and alterations to the MainReport and MasterQuery to improve the functionality of the database.

So, the current state of affairs is that I am successfully passing the SQL string to the RecordSource property of the report, but the problem is that Access tells me there is an error in the SQL string, and it will not actually run the report. Instead, the report stays in DesignMode and will not go into Report View. The error message says,

> Syntax error in query. Incomplete query clause

In attempting to diagnose the problem, I took the exact same SQL string (I literally copied and pasted it from the RecordSource property of report into the SQL View of a blank query), and to my surprise, the query runs beautifully. It returns the result set that I expect to see.  As a bonus, I even saved the query as Query1 and set the RecordSource of MainReport to Query1, and even this works!

I don't understand this behavior. I might expect that either they both work with the same SQL string or they both don't work, but I don't understand why they might behave differently; and this is the crux of my question.

So, why would a SQL string function properly as a query but not as the RecordSource of a report?

Thanks in advance for anyone who might have any ideas!

Comment: What is the SQL string and code that sets RecordSource? I advise against popup input prompts as inputs cannot be validated. If must use dynamic parameterized query then reference controls on form for user inputs.

Comment: Far too much text. A short, concise problem description is better than a book.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, since the query in its raw form will not run, and you fully pointed out that you "replace values in that query?

And since you ALSO point out that you are replacing the reports query source (and you MIGHT WANT to show and explain how you doing that?

So, given that you EACH TIME are going to modify the raw query? Then obvislity if you modify it for one time, then the values in that report (the critera) will have be changed. So, it ALSO not clear how you deal with that issue??

In most cases, becuase the query in its raw format has "values" that you going to replace, then in theory those values need to be "known" so you can repalce them.

Thus, as a general apporach for the above?

I save the raw query in the querybuilder, but then MAKE A COPY of that query, make the critera replacments and then SAVE that query to a 2nd query - a query that the report is based on.

So, say we have a simple query and report.

```
 qryHotelsS     (I put a "s" on such querys - means "source"
 qryHotels      (the final fixed up and changed query).
```

So, say I have this:

```
SELECT * FROM tblHotels WHERE City = '@City' ORDER BY HotelName.
```

So, I now might have some really nice prompt form, or form that allows the person to enter the city criteria, and then hit a view report button.

The code would thus look like this:

```
 Dim strSQL         As String
 Dim strCity        As String   ' for test - the value would no doubt come
                                ' from a very nice form wiht a text box, and
                                ' button to launch the report.
                                
 
 strSQL = CurrentDb.QueryDefs("qryHotelsS").SQL
 
 strCity = "Calgary"        ' as noted, this would be some text box value on
                             ' a nice report form
                             
 strSQL = Replace(strSQL, "@City", strCity)
 
 CurrentDb.QueryDefs("qryHotels").SQL = strSQL
 
 
 DoCmd.OpenReport "rptHotels", acViewPreview
```

So, we grab our "source" query, replace the values we want, and then save the query to a query that the report is based on, and then simple launch that report.

I mean, it really comes down to how your replacing and setting up the query now? The REALLY nice feature of above? You can run the code (comment out the open report command above). Once you run the above code, then you are rather free to open up the report and do further design and tweaking of the report, and since it has a valid query source, then you are free to design, change and setup the report any way you want. (since it has a valid sql query source).

so, adopt the idea of a having two queries for the report. The "source" query - with some values that you replace in VBA code. I just out of the blue used '@City', so I use @ signs, and you can roll your own quite much anyway you want. You could even leave in the [] and have your VBA replace the [], but I like using @ signs for this. And it works well even for dates.

eg:

```
 WHERE InvoiceDate = #@InvoiceDate#
```

So, in code, you can just replace @InvoiceDate with a date string, but the delimiters (#) don't need to be added.

## Edit: Why some query can't work in code?

Well, if you can take that string, shove it (save it) into a query, and then run the report on that query, then this can work.

However, there is a SIGNFICANT difference to use the DAO object model, and shoving sql into a reocrdset vs that of basing a form, or query on the same source.

Remember, the DAO recordset object does NOT allow and does NOT know about forms! Expressions etc., and they can't be used.

And if you introduce ANY VBA function into the sql? Once again, you cannot use the DAO querydef object.

The pure data engine (DAO) can be used from vb6, vb.net, c# etc. The data engine thus does not allow for example forms! expressions, and it ALSO does not allow use of custom VBA functions in that sql.

So, basing a reprot on a saved query def? No problem, both forms! expresisons, and even VBA functions can be contained in the sql query.

However, if you attempt to use the SAME query, and shove it into a DAO recordset? Then the so called "expression" service. (the system that resolves forms! expresions, and resolves VBA function calls) cannot be used.

That is due to the fact that the data base engine (JET/ACE) does not know about VBA, does not know aobut forms!, and it is a stand alone data engine, and a data engine NOT limited to being used with Access, but as noted can be used from FoxPro, vb.net, c#, vb6 etc. So, a pure DAO data engine call does not have nor allow forms! expressions, and as noted does not even allow you to have VBA expressions. It has to be 100% valid JET ONLY sql syntax. So, while some functions exist in JET sql, a good number of VBA ones are NOT allowed.

The JET database engine thus does NOT even know nor even assume that a forms! object exists, can be open, or closed, and the same goes for VBA functions used in that sql - in fact they can't be used.

So, if you put such expresisons in a query, and use from MS-ACCESS? Then the  query can be run from the UI, can be used as a data source to a report, but in pure VBA code, setting the same query to a DAO recordset object will fail.

So, it probably better to either:

```
Figure out if you have any VBA functions used in the sql
Figure out if you have any forms! expressions used in the sql
```

And then remove the above.

However, you might have a bit of a difficult time working through that messy sql, so you can then just shove that query string into a querydef ojbect (save it into the .SQL property as I did above), and then simple base the report on that saved query as opposed to trying to create a DAO recordset object in code, and using that for the forms reocrdsource, which as I point out above can't use forms! or VBA functions - and has to be pure valid JET/ACE syntax without such expressions.

Comment: Thank you for this suggestion! Your idea to have a report-source query at the ready and update its definition as needed is a great workaround!  I can't even believe I didn't think of it!  I've done a little testing with it, and sure enough, it's working!

Comment: Wanted to add:
I didn't post any of my SQL string b/c it's so long, and what really confounds me is why the SQL string **will** work in a query (and that named query will work as the RecordSource of the report) but why the **identical SQL string** will **not** work as the RecordSource of the report! If it's a syntax issue per the error message, why would it work in the query? How could the SQL string be syntactically well-formed for the query but not for the RecordSource property?

Comment: To clarify, I created a Master SQL String based on the original MainQuery. Where user input was required, I inserted placeholders surrounded by delimiters:
`SELECT * FROM Table1 WHERE ID = *Value1*`
The real string was over 6k characters long and stored in a table. The users interact with a form, which collected the user's input values. On button click, VBA code grabbed SQL string from table and replaced `*Value1*` with user input. Then, the report's RecordSource was set to the new SQL string. The output did not work as a report RecordSource, but it WOULD work as a query.

Comment: See my edit for the explain why this is so - the DAO jet/ace data engine object does NOT know about forms! expresisons, and does not know about VBA functions that you might use or have in the sql.

Comment: Thanks @Albert D. Kallal, your edit helps me understand the overall issues far better; so I've marked the question answered. To be clear, though, my SQL string did *not* contain any VBA whatsoever. My original SQL string was stored in a table. I used VBA to replace portions of it with user input values. Then, the manipulated SQL string was output and set to the RecordSource of the report. On the first pass, it worked perfectly fine as the RecordSource of the report. After I made changes to the SQL string, it stopped working as RecordSource of report. Yet, it still works as a query.

Comment: Not a problem. I still suspect that some left(), or ucase(), or mid() or some function is being used that requires the VBA/Access so called expression service. And of course such queries cannot auto prompt the user anymore either. As a general rule, the saved query, or building a DAO reocrdset should work, but the above issues such as Forms! expressions, VBA expressions, and even prompts in the query cannot be used.  You could do a debug.print in code to spit out the sql used, and then cut + paste into a new "test" query to see if the sql string in code is valid sql.